# How to get/fetch the authenticated User from Data Provider Class or Entity Class

Tags: api-platform.com

i'm using JWT authentication and all works correctly: i'm able to get the token and login successfully from Swagger UI.

Now I'm stucked because i'm not able to take the **authenticated User** instance from **Data Provider** Class or **Entity** Class, any suggestion?

Thanks

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I'm injected a Security instance in the DataProvider __construct so I can fetch the logged User!

Now I can use **$security->getUser()**.

```
namespace App\DataProvider;

use ApiPlatform\Core\DataProvider\ItemDataProviderInterface;
use ApiPlatform\Core\DataProvider\RestrictedDataProviderInterface;
use App\Entity\Order;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Security;

final class OrderItemDataProvider implements ItemDataProviderInterface, RestrictedDataProviderInterface {
    
private $security = null;

public function __construct(Security $security)
{
        $this->security = $security;
}

public function supports(string $resourceClass, string $operationName = null, array $context = []): bool {
        return Order::class === $resourceClass;
}

public function getItem(string $resourceClass, $id, string $operationName = null, array $context = []): ?Order {
        return new Order($id);
}

}
```